# LdaModel - random_state parameter not recognized - gensim

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gensim, topic-modeling

I'm using `gensim`'s `LdaModel`, which, according to the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html), has the parameter `random_state`. However, I'm getting an error that says:

```
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

Without the `random_state` parameter, the function works as expected. So, the workflow looks like this for those that want to know what else is happening...

```
from gensim import corpora, models
import numpy as np

# pseudo code of text pre-processing all on "comments" variable
# stop words
# remove punctuation (optional)
# keep alpha only
# stemming
# get bigrams and integrate with corpus (gensim makes this very easy)


dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(comments)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(comm) for comm in comments]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus) # change weights
corp_tfidf = tfidf[corpus] # apply them to corpus

# set random seed
random_seed = 135
state = np.random.RandomState(random_seed)

# train model
num_topics = 3
lda_mod = models.LdaModel(corp_tfidf, # corpus
                          num_topics=num_topics, # number of topics we want back
                          id2word=dictionary, # our id-word map
                          passes=10, # how many passes to take over the data
                          random_state=state) # reproduce the results
```

Which results in the error message above...

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

I'd like to be able to recreate my results, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commit/2e0ed26c03bfa997c8748d03fafe313a05cd9741), `random_state` parameter was added in the latest version (0.13.2). You can update your gensim installation with `pip install gensim --upgrade`. You might need to update `scipy` first, because it caused me problems.